# Order of Events - MSBuild and Task Runner Bindings (Gulp)

Tags: msbuild, gulp, task-runner-explorer

I am using a TFS build project to build a Visual Studio 2015 project that contains a gulpfile for compiling SASS among other things.  I am trying to understand the sequence of events using MSBuild Tasks and Task Runner bindings.  It appears that MSBuild knows enough to detect and run my default gulp task BeforeBuild:

```
/// <binding BeforeBuild='default' />
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var importer = require('sass-importer-npm');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src([
    './sass/**/*.scss',
    './node_modules/font-awesome/scss/**/*.scss'
  ])
    .pipe(sass({ importer: importer }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./Content/css'));
});
```

I am to using an MSBuild target to run after the BeforeBuild target so that I can include the generated files in the project for publishing:

```
<Target Name="CopyGulpFiles" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
```

Here is my MSBuild call in my build .proj file with the relevant info:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\MyProject.sln">
      <AdditionalProperties>
        VisualStudioVersion=$(VisualStudioVersion);
        OutputPath=$(OutputRoot);
        WebPublishMethod=FileSystem;
        publishUrl=$(StageFolder); 
        DeployOnBuild=false;
        DeployTarget=WebPublish;
        PublishProfile=$(MSBuildThisFileFullPath)
      </AdditionalProperties>
    </ProjectsToBuild>
  </ItemGroup>

<MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" Properties="Configuration=Dev"/>
```

These two things seem to run in the right order everytime I run them.  This raises some questions though:

- Would the 'BeforeBuild' binding for Task Runner get executed before the 'BeforeBuild' target in MSBuild?
- Are the order of bindings/targets deterministic here?
- Does using the AfterTargets property ensure that this is run after the whole 'BeforeBuild' stage (targets and bindings) are completed?
- How does MSBuild know how to use my Gulp file?  I assume it has to be the same mechanism as visual studio uses.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the issue where everything worked locally when building with the Task Runner, but Gulp was never called by MSBuild.

I ended up with the following solution, which extends the `Compile` task with our custom target `GulpBuild`. In this snippet `build` is the name of my Gulp task.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CompileDependsOn>
        $(CompileDependsOn);
        GulpBuild;
    </CompileDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="GulpBuild">
    <Exec Command="npm install" />
    <Exec Command="gulp build" />
</Target>
```

[Steve Cadwallader's post was very helpful in solving this issue.](http://www.codecadwallader.com/2015/03/15/integrating-gulp-into-your-tfs-builds-and-web-deploy/)

- The `BeforeBuild` target should always run before `BeforeBuild` in MSBuild. The Task Runner is specific to Visual Studio, so this will only happen when building in Visual Studio.
- [This will help with your questions about ordering.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171463.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar to that of @agressen, but updated from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56702293/2682623) and customized per Configuration:

```
<Target Name="GulpBuildUAT" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='UAT'">
        <Exec Command="npm install gulp" />
        <Exec Command="gulp build-release" />
    </Target>
```