# Running a target before the CoreBuild?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm adding a custom `.tt` template generation target to my project to run before `CoreBuild`, and there appear to be 2 ways of doing it:

```
<Project...>
    <Target Name="TransformOnBuild" AfterTargets="BeforeBuild">
</Project>
```

and

```
<Project...>
    <Target Name="TransformOnBuild" BeforeTargets="CoreBuild">
</Project>
```

If my target should run before my project is built, as the project relies on it, would it be better for me to use the latter?  I've seen the former used to do things like generate text templates, but it seems like an unreliable way to do it because it might get run after `CoreBuild`, which is too late.  Or is there some reason why `AfterTargets="BeforeBuild"` is still guaranteed to run before the core build?

I've also seen `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"` which will build even earlier.  Is this a better place to put a `.tt text generation target?

Answer (score 9):

Building on @stjin's answer, a good solution seems to be using

```
BeforeTargets="CoreCompile" DependsOnTargets="PrepareForBuild"
```

which is what the .net sdk (new-style csproj for .net core / standard projects) [is doing for automatic AssemblyInfo.cs generation](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/c428da3146d74c25b7776fb1759de51e96204280/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/build/Microsoft.NET.GenerateAssemblyInfo.targets#L47-L48).

It uses the following comment to explain why:

> Note that this must run before every invocation of CoreCompile to
>   ensure that all compiler runs see the generated assembly info. There
>   is at least one scenario involving Xaml  where CoreCompile is invoked
>   without other potential hooks such as Compile or CoreBuild, etc., so
>   we hook directly on to CoreCompile. Furthermore, we  must run *after* 
>   PrepareForBuild to ensure that the intermediate directory has been
>   created.

Note that the "intermediate directory" (`obj/[TargetFramework]` in this case) is where the output `.cs` file is placed in this case which may also be what  you might want to do.

Answer (score 4):

**Update 2**

Based on the [documentation from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx#Anchor_5):

This is the **Target Build Order**

1. InitialTargets targets are run.
2. Targets specified on the command line by the /target switch are run. If you specify no targets on the command line, then the DefaultTargets targets are run. If neither is present, then the first target encountered is run.
3. The Condition attribute of the target is evaluated. If the Condition attribute is present and evaluates to false, the target isn't executed and has no further effect on the build.
4. **Before a target is executed, its DependsOnTargets targets are run.**
5. **Before a target is executed, any target that lists it in a BeforeTargets attribute is run.**
6. Before a target is executed, its Inputs attribute and Outputs attribute are compared. If MSBuild determines that any output files are out of date with respect to the corresponding input file or files, then MSBuild executes the target. Otherwise, MSBuild skips the target.
7. After a target is executed or skipped, any target that lists it in an AfterTargets attribute is run.

These are the answers to your questions:

**If my target should run before my project is built, as the project relies on it, would it be better for me to use the latter?**

- No, because all the dependencies of *CoreBuild* will be executed before your *template generation target* and that will be too late.

**Or is there some reason why AfterTargets="BeforeBuild" is still guaranteed to run before the core build?**

- *AfterTargets="BeforeBuild"* guarantees that your target will be executed on time because it will be executed before all the *CoreBuild* dependencies.

**I've also seen *BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"* which will build even earlier. Is this a better place to put a `.tt text generation target?**

- In both cases *AfterTargets="BeforeBuild"* or *BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"* your target will be executed before all the *CoreBuild* dependencies, however in both cases you still have the risk to affect the results of your *template generation target* depending on what you have to execute in *BeforeBuild*. If you have this under control, you can use any of these options safely.

**Running a target before the CoreBuild?**

```
> there appear to be 2 ways of doing it.

    There are more options to achieve this. Please review below.
```

---

You should use the specific built in targets (BeforeBuild or AfterBuild) for this purpose. Thisis the mechanism provided by Microsoft to [safely extend the build process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366724.aspx) when using projects that depends on Microsoft.Common.targets

If you have only one target to run before CoreBuild, you can do this:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- add your tasks here -->
</Target>
```

If you have more than one target to run before CoreBuild, you can define a property with all the targets that needs to be called in the required order of execution:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BeforeBuildDependsOn>
      CustomTarget1;
      CustomTarget2;
      CustomTarget3
    </BeforeBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="BeforeBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(BeforeBuildDependsOn)"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on the fragment provided by @stijn:

*AfterTargets="BeforeBuild" will insert/execute the custom target like this: (Depends on BeforeBuild*

```
<BuildDependsOn>
  BeforeBuild;
       |-> Custom Target


  CoreBuild;
  AfterBuild
</BuildDependsOn>
```

*BeforeTargets="CoreBuild"* will insert/execute the custom like this (Depends on CoreBuild):

```
<BuildDependsOn>
  BeforeBuild;


       |-> Custom Target
  CoreBuild;
  AfterBuild
</BuildDependsOn>
```

So the "template generation target" will be executed in the same place (Between *BeforeBuild* and *CoreBuild*, but depending on different targets, that's why the apropriate Target to be used should be *BeforeBuild* inline or with dependencies.

Now regarding the 3rd party issue comment, the BeforeBuild/AfterBuild targets are intended for final users, the third party providers should implement their scripts without affect the basic workflow. These are some of the options a 3rd party should use to avoid breaking the regular flow:

Considering this as the base:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      BeforeBuild;
      CoreBuild;
      AfterBuild
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)"/>
```

**Option 1:** This will inject your custom 3rd party script before BeforeBuild without affect the default BuildDependsOn sequence, that still allows the final user to use the BeforeBuild target without.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      MyCustomThirdParty;
      $(BuildDependsOn);
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <MyCustomThirdPartyDependsOn>
      BeforeMyCustomThirdParty;
      CustomStep1;
      CustomStep2;
      CustomStep1;
      AfterMyCustomThirdParty
    </MyCustomThirdPartyDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="MyCustomThirdParty" DependsOnTargets="$(MyCustomThirdPartyDependsOn)"/>
```

**Option 2:** If the 3rd party script needs to be executed after the *BeforeBuild* target, this can be done like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
      BeforeBuild;
      MyCustomThirdParty;
      CoreBuild;
      AfterBuild
    </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

NOTE: In order for this to work properly, you must add the PropertyGroup and targets AFTER the Microsoft.CSharp.targets import.

This way you will be able to use multiple 3rd party scripts respecting the general workflow.

You can obviously use a combination of these options depending on the situation. But you should follow these general rules:

1. Respect the default workflow (BeforeBuild, CoreBuild, AfterBuild).
2. Include Before/After targets for your 3rd party script to allow the final user to inject anything before or after the 3rd party script execution.

These should be considered when you are using the default visual studio generated build scripts (Projects like .csproj, .vbproj, etc). If you are implementing your own scripts for other languajes or purposes, you can use BeforeTargets and AfterTargets wherever you want, but why don't you follow the good practices based on the existing scripts?

Comment: @Jez I read the question and I'm giving you the appropriate answer, what you are describing here is a common scenario, you want to execute one or more targets before the actual build process, that's why you have the BeforeBuild and AfterBuild targets available. You need to understand how the Microsoft MSBuild scripts are designed and the recommended practices, let me try to explain... BeforeBuild and AfterBuild are two "Empty" targets intended to be overwritten when you need to execute something before or after the actual build process preventing to break the build sequence...

Comment: You can overwrite these targets inline or by using a property group as mentioned in my examples, what you propose by using AfterTargets="BeforeBuild" or BeforeTargets="CoreBuild" will work, there's no real difference between them unless you have some logic inside the BeforeBuild target, in any case, this is not the appropriate practice, it will make your scripts hard to understand and maintain. If you want to convince yourself, you can generate a detailed MSBuild execution log running msbuild from the console and adding /v:diag at the end of your command.

Comment: @Rolo *there's no real difference between them* there is a major difference: the former will run before all dependent Corebuild steps (compilation etc) and the latter will run after it (at least in the 2 VS versions I tried).. Also I'd advice against using BeforeBuild/AfterBuild: they can be overridden by anyone, and as such provide only a limited single extension point: it is possible that if you override them and then import 3rd party code which does that again, or vice-versa, and only one of the versions will be called. Using Before/After/DependsOn attributes doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @stijn please review my update, I think it will clarify my answer.

Comment: You give good info on BuildDependsOn, but your explanation regarding AfterTargets="BeforeBuild" vs BeforeTargets="CoreBuild" is still not clear: you say *will be executed in the same place* but are ignoring that the CoreBuild target itself uses DependsOnTargets (including compilation etc). As such, the effect is very different: in the first case, the custom target runs *before* the dependencies of CoreBuild, in the second case it runs *after* the dependencie of CoreBuild. See https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Build.UnitTests/BackEnd/TargetBuilder_Tests.cs at line 937

Comment: Furthermore you are pointing out multiple times using BeforeBuild/AfterBuild is good practice. I don't know by which authority, but in any case it is debatable because apart from the 3rd part issue - which I agree is a bit far fetched - there are actually 2 other problems with it, which both are real (i.e. multiple occurrences of questions on the internet of people having the problem). And these problems do not exist for Before/After/DependsOn.

Comment: First: the location of BeforeBuild and AfterBuild in the projectfile matters: it *must* come after e.g. the Microsoft.CSharp.targets import.
This rather important info is missing from your answer.
Second: it works for C# projects but does not always work for other project types, e.g. at one point MS dropped BeforeBuild for C++.
So, all in all, given these clear disadvantages, I'm not sure AfterBuild and BeforeBuild really is good practice, when the alternatives work as well without less problems as far as I know.

Comment: @stijn you are right about the location of the properties in my examples, I'll update that, and I agree with you about the other project types, however, in this particular case, I think we are clearly talking about a C# project and the BeforeBuild target. My answer is not oriented to the specific language, it is an example of how it should be used in general.  Let me ask you a question... How do you guarantee the execution order when using AfterTargets/BeforeTargets if you have two targets A and B that should be executed before target C? Which one is executed first A or B?

Comment: @stijn thanks for the github link, I think your explanation on that paragraph explains the problem properly, I don't get that from the original question. You may want to edit the question with this information. I will take some time later today to validate what you say in that paragraph, right now I have some doubts.

Comment: As far as I know the ordering is defined by parsing order. Can either be in a list e.g. `Target Name="C" DependsOnTargets="A;B"`, or by ordering in the project file e.g. if `Target Name="A" BeforeTargets="C"` comes before `Target Name="B" BeforeTargets="C"`, this will first run A then B. In the second case if you want to force an order, e.g. B must run before A you have to establish that explicitly using `Target Name="B" BeforeTargets="A;C"`.

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets, the Build target is basically:

```
<BuildDependsOn>
  BeforeBuild;
  CoreBuild;
  AfterBuild
</BuildDependsOn>
<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)"/>

<PropertyGroup>
  <CoreBuildDependsOn>
    PrepareForBuild;
    PreBuildEvent;
    ...
    Compile;
    ...
    PostBuildEvent
  </CoreBuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="CoreBuild" DependsOnTargets="$(CoreBuildDependsOn)">
```

So using `BeforeTargets="CoreBuild"` will run before CoreBuild indeed, but that is *after* all it's dependent targets ran, so *after* all actual build steps. That's usually not what you want, instead if you want to run something before compilation etc, use `BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild"` or indeed `AfterTargets="BeforeBuild"` or even `BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild"`.

Comment: If you use `AfterTargets="BeforeBuild"`, is there not a risk of execution being: `BeforeBuild -> CoreBuild -> MyTarget`?

Comment: I don't think so: as far as I know 'AfterTargets' means 'immediately after target'. Then again, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee216359.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 is also not super clear on this. With an answer like Martin's you can force this 'run between X and Y' behaviour though.

Comment: @Jez working around BeforeBuild with AfterTargets, BeforeTargets or inside BeforeBuild itself is safe for you. Please take a look to the update I did to my answer, It explains the execution order of the targets and why you won't have problems if you work with BeforeBuild instead of CoreBuild.