# Using Pre and Post build actions in dotnet core csproj files

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I am a .NET Core novice and I am trying to set up a pre-build action in my csproj file. According to [1], we can use Target element to specify a pre-build step as follows:

```xml
<Target Name="MyPreCompileTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="generateCode.cmd"/>
</Target>
```

However, this element does not seem to be picked up by the MSBuild tool. My complete csproj file is given below:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="wwwroot\"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    

    <Target Name="MyPreCompileTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <Exec Command="echo meow meow"/>
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation.AspNetCore" Version="7.0.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="1.0.3"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\my-lib\<my-lib>.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

#### References

[1] - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj#the-csproj-format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` is a builtin of the command shell (`cmd.exe`) in that case so it won't work.

If you only use e.g. `generateCode`, msbuild will also look for `.bat` or `.sh` files matching that name depending on the platform you run on.

You can run the `dotnet build` command with `/v:diag` to get a full diagnostic output.

You can also verify if your target is actually run by adding a task like this inside the target:

```
<Message Importance="high" Text="Test Message" />
```

Also, since `echo` is available on mac, your project file does the expected when I run it on a Mac:

```
MacBook-Pro:footest martin$ dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.234.47922 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  footest -> /Users/martin/tmp/footest/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/footest.dll
  meow meow

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. The Message element and the diagnostic command helped me to narrow the issue. It  turns out the BeforeTargets="Build" does not execute the Task before the build step, instead I had to use "BeforeBuild". In my setup the build was failing because of the ProjectReference pointing to the custom lib which was not present (I was trying to use the pre-build action to clone the lib repo).I found the solution in this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986147/target-not-running-when-using-beforetargets-build-on-build-server. I think my question maybe a duplicate question.

Comment: If you use the step to `git clone` the other repo, it will probably not work anyway since you'd need to do an additional `dotnet restore` call to set up things to work correctly. Doing that as a before-build-event will likely cause trouble.

Comment: For these scenarios you are usually better off to just script the build in its own project file (https://gist.github.com/dasMulli/69f5303aa79a8cd4060e44891c90fd2d)

Comment: maybe also have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44043918/running-a-target-before-the-corebuild