# Why doesn't Exec Command work in a .csproj for netstandard2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj, .net-standard, execcommand

I'm busy moving my code from .Net Framework libraries to .netstandard2.0 libraries. So far it's going pretty well, but now i'm stuck with the  in the .csproj file.

The existing project file has this defined

```
  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <Exec Command="echo Now Rebuilding the package" />
  </Target>
```

the actual command executes an exe that generates a bunch of xml classes based on an xsd.

I cannot get this to work in a .netstandard2.0 project?

I've searched everywhere but i cannot find a reason for this not working...

Comment: I'm guessing it's just not supported yet/now/whatever. I really wish MS would get their house in order over this whole .Net core/standard/whatever it's called this week. The whole thing is a mess... I'll be sticking with the "old" framework until they sort all these problems out.

Comment: What have you searched for and what have you tried so far? I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44111808/1143474) which might prove useful

Comment: _I cannot get this to work_ what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @Liam: My experience is that the vast majority of it *is* supported - and ".NET Core" and ".NET Standard" are different things, which have had stable names for quite a while.

Comment: Maybe I'll just learn python like everyone else...

Comment: Did you run the build with /v:diag ? if not, please do and [edit] in what you've learned from that.

Comment: If you really named your target `Rebuild`, it will be overwritten by the SDK targets. you'll need to move to explicit sdk imports if you really want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in your specific instance, the `Rebuild` target will be overwritten by the sdk targets that are implicitly imported after your code. If you want to overwrite SDK-provided tasks, you need to change to explicit SDK imports (instead of `<Project Sdk="...">`):

```
<Project>
  <Import Project="Sdk.props" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <!-- other project content -->
  <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" />
  <Target Name="Build">
    <!-- overwrite Build target here -->
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <!-- overwrite Rebuild target here -->
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The `Exec` target is supported though the `echo` command may or may not work depending on the platform you are running it on (since `echo` may be just a built-in command of the shell but no executable that can be run).

Make sure that:

- The command starts with the path to an executable that is found on the `PATH` or is specified absolute or relative to the csproj file being built.
- The target is actually executed. E.g. some programs could use `/t:Clean;Build` instead of `/t:Rebuild`.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I added <Import Project="Sdk.targets" Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" /> to my project file and then all the targets("Rebuild", "Build" and "Clean") worked.

Comment: If this works for you, consider accepting the answer

Comment: Done, sorry didn't see the tick :)